# SQLite logic error while retrieving person name

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a doubt regarding the sqlite command that should be written for getting the name of MIN(count) and MAX(timestamp) and after retrieving, timestamp should be set for current timestamp amd and count should be incremented by 1.

[image]

For the first time, the table will be updates sa follows -

[image]

and for the next time, i have to update  the timestamp for lil to current timestamp. Then for the third time, jil's timestamp must be updated.

I have tried to work with this, but I am getting logical errors, the table is not getting updated as per the requirement. How can I implement this?

Comment: So, count would be the first parameter checked for lowest value and then the timestamp right?

Comment: Not clear! Can hardly figure out what you're trying to do..

Comment: yes @Harsh thats what I want to do.

Comment: @Nadeem_MK, I want to display name with condition, MIN(count) and MAX(timestamp), update count and timestamp(to current timestamp) and perform the same logic, to get all the names continuously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by making changes in the database. Initially, I have set the timestamp in descending order. then I wrote command to to display name with min(count)and   min(timestamp) and updated in the same order. This worked for me.